# Shared error messages not displaying when fields are invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, and I am having issues with error messages not displaying on forms. I've been stuck on this for several days and I've tried pretty much every solution/recommendation I've seen for this error but I haven't been able to make it work. I have to forms, one for users and one for greens. They are both using the same shared messages partial, and the users form displays error messages when input is invalid, but the greens form does not.

Greens form (displayed in greenmetrics view):

```
<%=form_for(@green) do |f| %>
  <%= render partial: 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-xs-2"><legend> Add new metrics:</legend></div>

          <div class="col-xs-2 ">
        <%= f.number_field :number, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Green number" %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-xs-2 ">
        <%= f.number_field :speed, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Green speed", :step => 'any' %>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-xs-2 ">
        <%= f.number_field :firmness, class: 'form-control',  placeholder: "Green firmness", :step => 'any'  %>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-xs-2 ">
        <%= f.date_field :measure_date, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Date of measurement" %>
        </div>
        </div
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-1 ">
        <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
        </div

  </div>

<% end %>
```

Users form:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Register') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

      <%= f.label :first_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :firstname, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :last_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :lastname, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :golf_course %>
      <%= f.text_field :golf_course, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :username %>
      <%= f.text_field :username, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Password Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Shared Messages Partial

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Greens model

```
    class Green < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order(measure_date: :desc, number: :asc) }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :number, presence: true 
  validates :speed, presence: true
  validates :firmness, presence: true
  validates :measure_date, presence: true

end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :greens, dependent: :destroy

  before_save { self.username = username.downcase}
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase}
  validates :firstname, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :lastname, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
                    #,uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false}
  validates :golf_course, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :username, presence: true, length: { maximum: 25 },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false}
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: {minimum: 6}

   # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

Controller

class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])    
    @greens = @user.greens
  end



    def greenmetrics
        @user = current_user  
        @greens = @user.greens
        @green = current_user.greens.build if logged_in?
end
```

Greens controller:

```
  def create
    @user = current_user
    @green = current_user.greens.build(green_params)
      if @green.save
        flash[:success] = "Green metrics saved!"
        @greens = @user.greens
        redirect_to (:back)
      else
        flash[:danger] = "Please verify that all data is valid"
        redirect_to (:back)
      end   
  end
```

I had to add flash danger since the error messages from the validation are not getting displayed...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong, I was missing the definition of each field as class: 'form-control'. Once I added that to the form and re-rendered if save was not successful, error messages started displaying.

Updated Form:

```
<%=form_for(@green, :url => greenmetrics_path, :html => {:method => :post}) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
      <section>
        <div class ="col-xs-2"><legend> Metrics for: </legend> </div>
        <div class ="col-xs-2"><%= f.date_field  :measure_date,  value: @date %></div>
      </section>
     <section>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-xs-2"><legend> Add metrics:</legend></div>
          <div class="col-xs-2 "> <%= f.number_field :number, placeholder: "Green number", class: 'form-control' %> </div>
          <div class="col-xs-2 "> <%= f.number_field :speed, placeholder: "Green speed", class: 'form-control', :step => 'any' %>  </div>
          <div class="col-xs-2 "> <%= f.number_field :firmness, placeholder: "Green firmness", class: 'form-control', :step => 'any'  %> </div>
          <div class="col-xs-2 "> <%= f.number_field :moisture, placeholder: "Green moisture", class: 'form-control', :step => 'any'  %> </div>
          <div class= "col-xs-1"> <%= f.submit "Add", class: "btn btn-primary" %> </div> 
       </div>
     </section>

<% end %>
```

Updated controller:

```
  def create
    @user = current_user
    @green = current_user.greens.build(green_params)
      if @green.save
        flash[:success] = "Green metrics saved!"
        @greens = @user.greens
        @measure_date = green_params[:measure_date]
        redirect_to greenmetrics_path(:date => @measure_date)
      else
        render 'greenmetrics'
        #flash[:danger] = "Please verify that all data is valid"
        #redirect_to (:back)
      end

  end
```

Answer (score 1):

A new green will never have any errors since it hasn't been validated.

Comment: The user form is also for a new user and it shows all invalid fields if you leave them black, don't enter a valid error etc. All validations are part of the model and require all fields to be present and conform to their type. Any thoughts?

Comment: The user form gets its user from the action. The green form *always creates a new green *.

Comment: I've tried passing it as a variable as well, sames as @user, but still the messages don't get displayed. I've added controller definitions as well

Comment: I don't see the greens controller.

Comment: Greens controller included. The only way I could get it to show an error message was if it failed upon save. Standard validation messages on the form are still not showing up. The only difference I can see is that users work and it's using users.new. Could this have anything to do?

Comment: Why are you redirecting?

Comment: The view has two components: horizontal line up to to add new records and a table underneath summarizing all existing records for that user. The redirect essentially refreshes the page after save to show the updates. Should I not be doing this?